# Unable to evaluate the expression Object has been collected

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, xpath, runtime, nosuchelementexception

There is one object from one class which is not getting identified during the runtime or debugging.
The same object gets highlighted on devtools. I'm not understanding what is wrong over here.
[image: I tried evaluating the expression. The object do get highlighted explicitly]

Does anyone have any idea what is the cause of this issue?
Let me know if require more details.

Comment: It would be more helpful if, instead of a screenshot, you posted the actual code fragment as text, and the result also as text. Screenshots are discouraged on StackOverflow. What is the value of `accountTitle`? What is the content of the HTML page? Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not getting highlighted during runtime was because it is the part of one iframe. After pointing my webDriver to the iframe and then the object , my code was running successfully.